# SQL Server update duplicate file records based on order of file format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Following is the input records:

```
FILENAME    FLAG
file1.DOC   1
file1.DOCX  0
file1.WLL   1
file1.DOT   1
file1.WBK   1
file1.WIZ   1
file2.DOCX  0
file2.WLL   1
file2.DOT   1
file3.WBK   1
file3.WIZ   1
file3.DOC   0
file4.WBK   0
file4.WIZ   1
file4.WLL   1
```

There are duplicate filename without extension. The priority of choosing the file with extension is in order: DOCX > DOC > DOT > WBK > WLL > WIZ
I need to update the FLAG column has shown where I set 0 to highest priority found from the order and remaining to Flag 1.

In the above example, DOCX format has highest priority hence the Flag is set to 0 for file1 and for remaining formats, file1 is set to 1. Similarly WBX extension has higher priority than WIZ and WLL, hence file4.WBK is set to 0 and file4.WIZ, file4.WLL is set to 1.

```
With CTE as( 
Select FILENAME, (SUBSTRING(FILENAME, 0, LEN(FILENAME) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(FILENAME)) + 2)) AS FILENOEXT, row_number() over (partition by FILENOEXT order by FILENAME) as COLLIDE from FILESDATA
)
UPDATE CTE
    SET FLAG = CASE
            WHEN SUBSTRING(FILENAME, LEN(FILENAME) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(FILENAME)) + 2, LEN(FILENAME))='WIZ' THEN 1 ELSE
                WHEN SUBSTRING(FILENAME, LEN(FILENAME) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(FILENAME)) + 2, LEN(FILENAME))='WLL' THEN 1 ELSE
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(FILENAME, LEN(FILENAME) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(FILENAME)) + 2, LEN(FILENAME))='WBK' THEN 1 ELSE
                        WHEN SUBSTRING(FILENAME, LEN(FILENAME) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(FILENAME)) + 2, LEN(FILENAME))='DOT' THEN 1 ELSE
                            WHEN SUBSTRING(FILENAME, LEN(FILENAME) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(FILENAME)) + 2, LEN(FILENAME))='DOC' THEN 1 ELSE
            END END END END END
        WHERE COLLIDE > 1   ;
```

Comment: Is there a better way to write the query?

Comment: There have been 2 answers offered.  Was your question addressed?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select fd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by left(filename, charindex('.', filename))
                                order by (case when filename like '%.DOCX' then 1
                                               when filename like '%.DOC' then 2
                                               when filename like '%.DOT' then 3
                                               when filename like '%.WBK' then 4
                                               when filename like '%.WLL' then 5
                                               when filename like '%.WIZ' then 6
                                               else 999
                                          end)
                                ) as seqnum
      from files_data fd
     )
update toupdate
    set flag = (case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
    where flag <> (case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end);
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. I will post updates on testing on the actual data set.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a table driven approach

```
with f_cte as (
    select f.*, row_number() over (partition by ext.stem order by v.ordinal) rn
    from #FILESDATA f
         cross apply
         (select charindex('.',reverse(f.[filename])) ndx, len(f.[filename]) ln) st
         cross apply
         (select left(f.[filename], st.ln-st.ndx) stem,
                 right(f.[filename], st.ndx-1) ext) ext 
         join
         (values (1, 'DOCX'), 
                 (2, 'DOC'),
                 (3, 'DOT'),
                 (4, 'WBK'),
                 (5, 'WLL'),
                 (6, 'WIZ')) v(ordinal, extention) on ext.ext=v.extention)
update f_cte
set flag=case when rn=1 then 0 else 1 end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. I will post updates on testing on the actual data set.